# Show records being processed in status bar

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2000

I have a query that I process by looping through each record via VBA.  It takes a while to run and the users are impatient.  To them it appears that the program has locked up.  How do I control the status bar to show the user that the query is in process and working?

I want it to show something like:

```
TOTAL RECORDS 95551, PROCESSING: 85
```

The 85 in the above example would increment all the way up until it reached the 95551.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below should do what it is you are looking for.  Visually the progress bar will also move accordingly.

```
Dim tempRN AS Long, tempRT AS Long

tempRN= 1

'Get the total number of records that you need to work with and assign to tempRT

Application.SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "TOTAL RECORDS " & tempRT & ", PROCESSING: " & tempRN, tempRT

Do While .......
  'Do whatever it is you need to do

  tempRN = tempRN + 1
  Application.SysCmd acSysCmdRemoveMeter
  Application.SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "TOTAL RECORD COUNT " & tempRT & ", PROCESSING: " & tempRN, tempRT
  Application.SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, tempRN
Loop

Application.SysCmd acSysCmdRemoveMeter
```